# Chrome-like omnibar in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, search, firefox-extensions

How to make Firefox's awesome bar (address bar) to work like in Google Chrome? I mean especially search (words search, not URLs) auto complete from search history.

[This addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/omnibar/) does not answer my question, but I like to use it too. It suggests words search from search engine suggestions list, but I want also suggestions from phrases, which I input earlier (like in Chrome), immediately showing it in the awesome bar in blue (or red) color while I type. Also I want auto saving of these suggestions between browser restart.

I want like this, but not only for URLs suggestions (I want for words suggestions from my search history too):

[image: Google Chrome omnibox search]

P.S: Omnibox is the other name for Omnibar addon, which does not satisfy my requests as I wrote in my question.

P.P.S: I don't want *search completion* from URLs and tittle of sites as in the addon [Prospector - Speak Words](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/prospector-speak-words/)

Comment: What is wrong with simply typing your search into your address bar, exactly? I can search words that will auto complete if I have searched them before. You can even set keywords like g for google, a for amazon and make simple searches like "g whatever" and get search results on whatever.

Comment: @Dispensador Of course I use keywords. But I want [this (see image)](http://s9.postimg.org/jezt7vcsf/02_07_2014.png) not only for URLs, but for word phrases too (as in Google Chrome). I want suggestions with immediate auto complete of first in awesomebar (addressbar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blog from Mozilla has already shown how to [Combine Your Firefox Search Bar and Address Bar](https://blog.mozilla.org/theden/2013/04/17/combine-your-firefox-search-bar-and-address-bar/) since 2013, suggesting the [Foobar add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foobar/?src=external-denblog)

> The Foobar add-on lets you integrate the functionality of the search bar into the address bar, making searching and navigation quicker and easier for those who like a combined experience.

For more suggestions see [Combine Firefox Address Bar and Search Bar into One Like Chrome](https://www.techgainer.com/combine-firefox-address-bar-search-bar-like-chrome/)

However you can already search from the address bar without a keyword even before that, since [at least 2010](https://www.maketecheasier.com/6-tips-and-tricks-for-firefox-address-bar/). There's also a blog from Mozilla in 2012 talking about [Easy Awesome Bar Search](https://blog.mozilla.org/theden/2012/04/23/firefox-tips-easy-awesome-bar-search/). If you don't want to see the search bar just right click on the toolbar > customize and remove the search bar. See

- [Search the web from the address bar](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/search-web-address-bar?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Location%20bar%20search)
- [How To Use Firefox 4's "Awesome Bar" To Make Search Faster](https://www.businessinsider.com/how-to-use-the-location-bar-aka-awesome-bar-to-search-the-internet-faster-in-firefox-4-2011-4)

Later in Firefox 57 Mozilla has [turned off the search bar by default](https://www.ghacks.net/2017/09/09/firefox-57-search-bar-off-by-default/), with an option to change between the two layouts

[image: Firefox search bar option]

- [Change your default search settings in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-your-default-search-settings-firefox?&mobile=0)
- [Add or Remove Search Bar in Firefox](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/97982-add-remove-search-bar-firefox.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Beyond Australis](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-fox-only-better/). This addon can change the results displayed in the Firefox Awesomebar.

> recent history, your bookmarks, other open tabs, searches the web using your favorite search engine and can even show you suggestions to search for.

If it's incompatible, use [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/checkcompatibility/).

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score -2):

Install [Omnibox add-on](http://bestthings4u.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-use-omnibox-in-mozilla.html) in Mozilla. It's very easy and works same as in Chrome.

Comment: You did not read my question. I wrote, that Omnibar addon is not the same as in Google Chrome. This addon does not satisfy my requests. That page only named Omnibar addon as Omnibox addon.